# Two click functions doing the same thing with difference the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery click functions:

```
$childCheckbox.click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('checked') && !$parentCheckbox.hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked');
        $parentCheckbox.prop('indeterminate',true);     
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).removeAttr('checked', 'checked').removeClass('checked');
        $parentCheckbox.prop('indeterminate',false);
    }
});

$subparentCheckbox.click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('checked') && !$parentCheckbox.hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').addClass('checked');
        $parentCheckbox.prop('indeterminate',true);     
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
        $(this).removeAttr('checked', 'checked').removeClass('checked');
        $parentCheckbox.prop('indeterminate',false);
    }
});
```

As you can see both are exactly the same with the exception of the "selector". Is there a good way to combine these to minimize code?

Comment: Tip: Store the result of `$(this)` in a temporary variable to avoid repeated calls to jQuery: `var $this = $(this);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 - there are more, no doubt

1. Give both checkboxes a class and use that as the selector

   ```
   $(".someClass").click( ... )
   ```
2. Declare the event handler elsewhere, and use it anywhere:

   ```
   function checkboxClick(event) {...};  

   $subparentCheckbox.click(checkboxClick);  
   $childCheckbox.click(checkboxClick);
   ```
3. Use `.add` to combine the two checkboxes into one collection before calling `.click` like so

   ```
   $subparentCheckbox.add($childCheckbox).click(...)`
   ```

Comment: You can call the .on() method straight away, since if you look in jQuery source, .click() refers right back to .on() anyways.

Comment: @JonnySooter True. I actually prefer using `.on()` in my own code even when there are aliasses like `.click()`. Keeps the code consistent.