# Opening social media links in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rather new to jQuery but managed to get some social links to open in a new controlled window instead of new tab. I have a few functions that do the same thing, and this works, but there is always a better method.

I did review the question and answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22976/jquery-two-click-functions-doing-the-same-thing-only-difference-is-the-selecto) and couldn't figure out which would apply to this case.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#ssba_facebook_share").attr('title','opens in a new pop-up');
  $("#ssba_facebook_share").click(function(){
    w = parseInt((screen.width - 600)/2); h = parseInt((screen.height - 400)/2);
    cwin = window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'closewin',
   'status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=400,width=600');
    cwin.moveTo(w,h);
    return false;
  });
  $("#ssba_twitter_share").attr('title','opens in a new pop-up');
  $("#ssba_twitter_share").click(function(){
    w = parseInt((screen.width - 600)/2); h = parseInt((screen.height - 400)/2);
    cwin = window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'closewin',
   'status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=400,width=600');
    cwin.moveTo(w,h);
    return false;
  });
  $("#ssba_google_share").attr('title','opens in a new pop-up');
  $("#ssba_google_share").click(function(){
    w = parseInt((screen.width - 600)/2); h = parseInt((screen.height - 400)/2);
    cwin = window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'closewin',
   'status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=400,width=600');
    cwin.moveTo(w,h);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Now, I've attempted a few things to no avail, and one method was this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#ssba_facebook_share","#ssba_twitter_share","#ssba_google_share").attr('title','opens in a new pop-up');
    $(this).click(function(){
      w = parseInt((screen.width - 600)/2); h = parseInt((screen.height - 400)/2);
      cwin = window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'closewin',
      'status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=400,width=600');
      cwin.moveTo(w,h);
      return false;
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any pointers in this, if possible, with a description of where I went wrong? Or even post a link to a question that goes over this in laymen terms? (I've been looking around and found similar posts, which is how I arrived at where I am now, but still having trouble making complete sense of it.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you declare your variables using [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly declares it as
>   a global variable (it is now a property of the global object)

Personally, I'd probably add a class to the links in question like `shareLink` then you could simply do:

`$(".shareLink")` to select all three links

Alternately, you could try selecting by id ending in `_share` assuming that quality is unique to these three links:

`$("[id$='_share']")`

I'd also suggest chaining so that your whole code would be something like this:

```
$("[id$='_share']").click(function(){
    var w = parseInt((screen.width - 600)/2)
    ,   h = parseInt((screen.height - 400)/2)
    ,   cwin = window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'closewin',
               'status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,directories=0,
               resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=400,width=600');
    cwin.moveTo(w,h);
    return false;
  }).attr('title','opens in a new pop-up');
```

Finally, I'd review the documentation on [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.open#Position_and_size_features) to be sure you don't want to provide `left` or `top` parameters, instead of immediately moving the window, or even a different solution. Make sure you at least read the section on [Usability issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.open#Usability_issues)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware I could use attribute selectors like in css (which I'm much more familiar with). so I could have gone with either `id^=ssba_`, `id$=_share`, or `id*=ssba_` / `id*=_share`. The links are generated from a plugin in wordpress, to prevent breaking anything should the plugin update I don't want to edit the actual plugin source files (e.g. no classes). So in this case both "ssba_" and "_share" are unique to the links generated. I'll definitely read up on 'window.open' and eventually do away with the plugin and build a modal in it's place. But great post, thanks for the insight!

Comment: @darcher Yes, I believe all of those would work. Jquery provides all sorts of [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) which is part of why it's so popular.